# Where to put Data Logic in MVC?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

When setting up a MVC project I like to have seperate projects in my Visual Studio Solution. One project handles the main things, like Controllers and Views, and then I have a separate project for the Data Layer and one project for Utilities. The Main project references both the other projects. The Data Layer references the Utilities project.

With this structure I am facing a problem, when I try to implement a utility method like this:

```
public static string GetCountryFromID(int id)
{  
   dev_Entities dbContext = new dev_Entities();
   var country = from c in dbContext.countries
                 where c.id == id
                 select c;

   return country.FirstOrDefault().country_name.Trim(); 
}
```

The method works with the Database, but my Utilities project can't reference the Data Layer project, because otherwise there would be a circular dependancy, which is forbidden by Visual Studio. So what is the best way to work on the Database and where should I put the belonging utility methods?

**Edit:**
I chose this example for a utility method, because it's an action I have to do often and I would like to avoid duplicate code.

Comment: Maybe it's obvious, but what part of this code references your Utilities project?

Comment: Why do you call that a "utility method"? It's very clearly accessing your database.

Comment: If your data layer has a rigid structure and you need a more flexible piece that accesses the same context you can make a partial class. Truly not a separate layer, but logically so.

Comment: Only reference the DbContext from inside your data layer project - nowhere else.  I'm assuming from your sample is from your Utilities project.

Answer (score 1):

Regarding structure of the project, It is important to have separation by means of different project, for example Business logic, data access, utilities and so on.

This helps in achieving separation of concerns. But this is just one first step towards separation of concerns. To further strengthen it, use of interfaces is encouraged so that one implementation can be swapped easily with other type of implementation.

Regarding the issue of circular dependency, the method put up in Utility is not exactly a utility method, it is more of a data access method. I feel access to DBcontext should be done in a controlled manner from data layer project only.

Answer (score 1):

> First Question: Is this a recommended structure?

Yes.

> Second Question: With this structure I am facing a problem...

From your limited code example, I can't see where the conflict is. But, your Data Access project should have one job, and one job only: Talk to the database.

Your Data Access project SHOULD NOT NEED to know anything about your Utilities project. There should be nothing in the Utilities project that is needed by the Data Access project to talk to the database.

Also, you should not call the Data Access project from within the Utilities project either. The two should really not even know that the other exists.

A common structure should look like this, in a simple web-based app:

```
                  [UI]
                   |
             [Business Logic]
               |         |
           [Utility]  [DataAccess]
```

Where each `|` represents a reference.

The method in your example, `GetCountryFromID` should be in the DataAccess project.

**EDIT:**

I should also add: It looks like you are using Entity Framework (EF). Your Data Access project should be the only project that has the EF .dll's in it. None of the other projects should know anything about EF. Among other advantages, if you ever want to swap out your data access tools (say to something like Dapper) then this change would only impact a single project.

Answer (score 1):

What I usually do is on how I "architecture" my projects:

`API/MVC` with reference only to my `DAL Services` and `DTOs`

Then in my `DAL`, I split it up into two, `Commands` and `Queries`, with each action/query/update/create on each own class file. Also I either I add their my `DTOs` or on a different project. And they only references my Utilities/Services (String transformation, enum to string, etc.)

In your case, I would not call your `GetCountryById` as Utility or Service as it access database and only returns string. I would put it in my `DAL>Queries` as it access the database and only return a specifc part of it.